# UIImage can't be initialed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I want to use `NSString` to initial `UIImage`.But I failed.here is my code

```
UIImage *tImage=[UIImage imageNamed:file];//file is NSString @"1Shux.png"
        if (!tImage) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is nil",file);
        }
```

And Xcode log

```
2013-06-13 11:23:57.883 HuaHe2[3048:907] 1Shux.png is nil
```

But I actually add the 1Shux.png to project,and in Copy Bundle Resources,there is 1Shux.png.In addition,I use another file to initial `UIImage` before,and I succeed.But this time I change the  image,then I failed.

Comment: *sidenote:* `[UIImage imageNamed:]` is notorious of memory leakage.

Comment: do you include the image in the project build ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I drag the image to project.and in Copy Bundle Resources,there is 1Shux.png

Comment: If you click on the image in project navigator, make sure in file inspector the "target membership" section has checkbox checked.

Comment: check the image in build phase>copy bundle resources... Click on your project in project navigator(the blue image)>>select build phase(right side)>>copy bundle resources>>type your image name in searchbar. if it is not exists. add this image using + button below.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor What do you mean by "memory leakage"? It's possible to misuse memory this way, but leakage is a different think altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the solution:delete all the files under ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData ,then everything works well.But I don't know why.